# What is the difference between an include, a partial, and/or a block in templating. EJS / ejs-locals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templating, ejs

I have been using [**EJS**](http://embeddedjs.com) with Express and Node.JS for a little while now and I think I understand the basics. I have experimented with the EJS `include` function which has allowed me to include one template inside of another. I have also used a library called [**ejs-locals**](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) which provides easy true layout support. One thing I noticed is that ejs-locals also defines `partial` and `block` functions which may be used with EJS. I cannot seem to find a good explanation on what the differences between these three concepts are. As far as I can tell they are general concepts to templating and not only EJS. It seems to me that both `partial` and `block` are still ways of including other template files, but how do they differ?

Comment: here is a block implementation in ejs https://github.com/dheeraj-br/ejs_layout_implementation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`include`: Simply takes the content from the given file and places it where your `include` statement is. In other words: The file has access to all variables defined in the file it has been included from.

`partials`: Pretty much the same as `include`, with the difference that the partial has only access to the variables that you pass to it when rendering.

`blocks`: In your layout you define locations where your blocks' content should be. In the file you render, you define contents for these blocks and define the layout you would like your block content to be rendered to.